# How to use autolayout, to make compatible for iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 both?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, autolayout

I have custom upside tab bar and using storyboards. I have followed this tutorial [custom tab bar](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/tutorial/ios-5-creating-a-custom-side-tabbar-using-storyboards-and-custom-segues/)

This tutorial explains about side tabBar and I am using upside tabBar with same approach. I am using autolayout and need to make compatible for iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 both. When I design in 4 inch screen, it runs good for iPhone 5 and for iPhone 4, it cuts bottom 88 pixels(difference in iPhone 4 and iPhone 5), and if I design for 3.5 inch screen, it is good for iPhone 4 and shows blank space for bottom 88 pixels.
Actually I am newbie for autolayout and how can I implement this for my project?
Thanks in advance for any help.

This is design for iPhone 5 [image: iphone 5 screen]
but it looks like this, when runs on 3.5 inch screen [image]

Comment: The only answer to this can only be, your constrains are wrong. If you need a better answer, please provide more information. (I don't have the time to read the tutorial to figure out at which point you could have done something wrong.)

Comment: @dasdom I have added design for reference.